# bundle rspec /spec is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, integration-testing

I'm trying to run a test suite using rspec with the command(s)

```
bundle exec rspec /spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

or

```
bundle exec rspec /spec/requests
```

Results in the following error messages:

```
/Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': cannot load such file -- /spec/requests (LoadError)
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

I receive this error Even if i revert back to a default test file like:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

it seems like I've messed up the gem but I'm unsure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please paste your `spec_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the leading forward slash:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```